# How can I make a DualShock 4 show only once when connected both by Bluetooth and USB?

Tags: pc, controllers, windows

I have a DualShock 4 connected via Bluetooth and USB to my PC. How can I make it show only once so I can keep it charging without getting double inputs?

[image]

Comment: I cannot offer an answer to fix the problem, but a workaround would be to try using a cable that is capable of only charging (rather than providing power)

Comment: I have that option but i don't want to do it lol (I know how to make my own cables)